# How to stop a program from ever running unless specifically started by user and then kill it again after close Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I am looking to stop a program from ever running unless specifically started by a user and once the user logs out it auto-kills and goes back to a disabled state.

I would not mind if I had to use the Windows Task Manager to close it but I don't want it to start again.

I'm using Windows 11

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How else is a program executed unless it’s started by a user? If an application has an Autorun registry key, it’s being ran by the user, just automatically. There isn’t a way to tell the difference between a user running the application and that Autorun key (or another application starting an application).

Comment: Do you mean by one specific user? That System should not start it?

Comment: Most applications are closed once user logout anyways. Are you talking about some specific app with specific behavior?